# 読み込んだ画像の範囲指定したところを黒く塗りつぶしたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

※いただいたコメントにより修正しました。

下記の機能を実装したwebサイトを制作したいです。

・画像URLを入力またはアップロードで取得した画像をブラウザに表示する
・表示した画像にマウスカーソルをのせると、PhotoshopやIllustratorで言うところのペンツールのような機能を持った**ツールA**※1に切り替わる
・**ツールA**で三角形以上の多角形を作ると、その多角形の内側を黒ベタに塗りつぶす
・黒ベタが施された状態の画像※2を保存できるボタン
※1：**ツールA**の動きは直線のみで、例えで出したペンツールに実装されているカーブ生成機能並びにカーブを調整するハンドルは不要です。
※2：画像サイズとファイル形式は元画像のまま。

以上です。
下図は上記の機能を分かりやすくするためと、使用手順を説明する趣意の図です。
※下図において画像読込機能については都合により省略します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

現状は画像読込機能のみ、HTML,css,jsで実装できました。
下記サンプルです。
https://jsbin.com/fojaqedito/edit?html,js,output
しかし、その他の機能についてはどの言語で、どのように書けば実装できるのかが分からず困っています。
できればHTML,css,jsで実装したいですが他言語でも構いません。
ご助力お願いいたします。

```js
$(function () {
  
  //input url
  $('#url').change(function () {
    $('#main_file').fadeOut(1);
    $('#main_url').fadeIn(500);
    $('#view_url').prop('src', this.value);
    console.log(this.value);
    var file = $('#file')[0];
    file.value = "";
  });
  //input file
  $('#file').change(function (e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#main_url').fadeOut(1);
    $('#main_file').fadeIn(500);
    $('#view_file').prop('src', e.target.result);
    var url = $('#url')[0];
    url.value = "";
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
  });
  
  //close
  $('.close').click(function () {
    $('.main').fadeOut();
    var url = $('#url')[0];
    url.value = "";
    var file = $('#file')[0];
    file.value = "";
  });
  
});
```

```css
.main{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- input URL -->
  <input id="url" type="text" placeholder="URLを入力">
  <!-- input file -->
  <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <!-- output url -->
  <div id="main_url" class="main">
    <img id="view_url" class="view">
    <button class="save">保存</button>
    <button class="close">クリア</button>
  </div>
  <!-- outoput file -->
  <div id="main_file" class="main">
    <img id="view_file" class="view">
    <button class="save">保存</button>
    <button class="close">クリア</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 検索するとこんなのがあります。[ユーティリティ - 画像編集の記事一覧](https://www.moongift.jp/tag/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86)  [Drawer.js](https://www.drawerjs.com/) とかが良さそうですね。

Comment: 塗りつぶした後、どうしたいのかによってアプローチが異なってきますので、もう少し具体的な目的を提示された方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 更新された画像からは、塗りつぶすだけでなく、保存も行いたいと読み取れました。であれば画像の生成も必要なはずです。求める内容を文章で説明してください。

Comment: クライアント側だけで完結させる感じですか？クライアントで編集とのことで`canvas`を使うのが手っ取り早いかと思いますが、URL長の関係で`datauri`の形で保存させるサイズには限界があると思います。あとサーバ側で処理しないなら`anchor`タグの`download`などでダウンロードさせるか、右クリックで保存させることになると思いますが、`anchor`の`download`はブラウザによってサポートされない場合もあるので注意が必要です。 https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: クライアント側だけ完結させます。datauriについて知らなかったので調べたところ、2MBが限界の目安のようですね。（http://var.blog.jp/archives/71618647.html）ブラウザのサポートについても一旦は置いておいて、ひとまずは機能の実装を目指したいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<canvas>` で実装するのがベストかと思います。コードは大きくなりそうなので、方針だけ書きます。

1. 指定された画像を `<canvas>` に描画する
2. 範囲指定のUIを実装する。`click`イベントハンドラで座標を記録して線を描くなど。
3. 範囲指定がおわったら、

   1. 指定領域を黒く塗る
   2. [`toBlob()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-toblob)で画像をエンコードする。
   3. エンコードが終わったら、[保存]ボタンを `<a download>`で作り、その href に [`URL.createObjectURL(blob)`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-createObjectURL) で生成したblob URLをセットする。

個々のステップの実装で疑問がでたら個別に質問を立てるとよいかと思います。